# Using Eclipse IDE on an Android tab?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there any way to use Eclipse IDE on an Android tab? I mean, developing any app on Android (JAVA, PHP, C, etc.), not developing Android apps on any other OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse itself does not run on Android.

The only IDE I am aware of for Android that runs on Android itself is AIDE: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking for an IDE to develop any kind of apps (JAVA, PHP, C, etc.) on Android. I edited my question.

Comment: @sp00m: That does not change my answer. Eclipse itself does run on Android, and both of your sentences containing question marks are asking about Eclipse.